# Does controller PWM frequency need to match ESC PWM frequency?

Tags: pwm, motor-controller

I am working on a project now where I have encountered a new class of hardware called ESC (electronic speed controller). I am looking at this ESC now: https://www.amainhobbies.com/hobbywing-quicrun-waterproof-1080-brushed-crawling-esc-23s-hwa30112750/p564169 and it says that the PWM frequencies are 1/2/4/8/16kHz. I am assuming that these PWM frequencies refer to the frequencies available to drive a motor in conjunction with varying duty cycles.

I am having trouble understanding how the PWM frequency of a controller factors into this. For example, Arduino Nano PWM frequency is 490Hz on most pins, but 980Hz on a few others. I believe that Pixhawk 2.4.8 PWM frequency can be 50Hz or 400Hz? Regardless of what controller is used, does the controller output PWM frequency need to "match" (be equal to) the PWM frequency of the ESC for it to run? Or can ESCs accept any "input PWM frequency" to drive a motor at the chosen PWM frequency on the ESC? If I send a 50Hz PWM signal of a given duty cycle to the ESC, will the ESC be able to output a 1/2/4/8/16kHz PWM signal of a given duty cycle? Not sure how else to ask this question.

Thanks.

Comment: `Pixhawk 2.4.8 PWM frequency can be 50Hz or 400Hz` ... that refers to the control signal between the remote control and the ESC ... it is the same as the control signal for a hobby servo

Comment: your question belongs at https://drones.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ttyTrxB0OmA